# gcc -Wpadded does not provide any warning

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to use gcc's -Wpadded option to know if gcc can help me in finding out whether a structure is padded or not. This is the following code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct my {
    char *name;
    int age;
} my_details;

int main() {
    struct my person1;
    return 0;
}
```

I complied the code using the following. `gcc -Wpadded alignment_demo.c`. It did not return any warnings. So is my structure not padded or I am missing something? `man gcc` however shows it supports an option called -Wpadded. Kindly help

Thanks
Chidambaram

Comment: What are the sizes of `char*` and `int`? If they're equal, there will be no padding.

Comment: @DanielFischer Nice catch, when i changed to `char name` I got the warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems that pack struct default is - 4. (`gcc -fpack-struct=4`)
If it so - than this structure is already aligned.
Because

```
char* - 4 or 8 bytes
int - 4 bytes
```

If you run this, you will have warning:

```
azat:~$ gcc -Wpadded -fpack-struct=8 -o test /tmp/test.c
/tmp/test.c:6:1: warning: padding struct size to alignment boundary [-Wpadded]
```

Because of the `int`.