# Will gcc pack-struct decide how many padding is added to structs?

Tags: c, gcc, struct, bit-fields

I read this article from E.S.R [The Lost Art of C Structure Packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/), and the code is follow(excerpted from packtest.c):

```
$ cat p.c
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo5 {
    short s;
    char c;
    int flip:1;
    int nybble:4;
    int septet:7;
};   

main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    printf("sizeof(struct foo5)   = %zu\n", sizeof(struct foo5));
}
$ gcc -Wpadded -o p p.c
p.c:9:1: warning: padding struct size to alignment boundary [-Wpadded]
 };
 ^
$ ./p
sizeof(struct foo5)   = 8
$ gcc -Wpadded -fpack-struct=2 -o p p.c
p.c:9:1: warning: padding struct size to alignment boundary [-Wpadded]
 };
 ^
$ ./p
sizeof(struct foo5)   = 6
```

So how many trailing padding to the struct will diff on different pack-struct size? And how could I use pahole to see exactly how many padding is added? The default pack-struct value is [8 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762970/gcc-wpadded-does-not-provide-any-warning).

Comment: I found out that you have declare one(static allocated on stack) like this `struct foo5 f5;` to get pahole work, or pahole will report nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be 'trailing padding'. 
C99 says:

> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large
>   enough to hold a bitfield.

in your struct the bitfield doesn't need 4 bytes.

I guess pahole doesn't see the struct because the program doesn't have that information. sizeof operator gets a constant so that information is not needed. You can try `info types`' in gdb to see if that type is available.

Comment: `pahole` requires `libelf` and `libdw` to get the work done, may be it  just analysis the debug info not stripped. So if no declaration of struct variables, it will find nothing useful about paddings(what is done by compilers) ?